# Flutter: how to get the number of subcollections of a document in firebase firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections, document

How do I determine the number of subcollections within a firebase document?
My data looks as follows: [image: firebase data]
And I am trying to get the number of subcollections within each skill document. I tried something like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("skills")
        .doc(widget.category)
        .snapshots()
        .length;
```

but that just returns null.

Comment: You may be interested by this article: [How to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get a count of, or otherwise dynamically retrieve, the subcollections of a document. The common workaround is to store information about what collection exist in the parent document, update that on every create in/delete from a subcollection, and read it from there.